# How to get CookieManager from Jmeter in groovy?

Tags: cookies, groovy, jmeter

I don't want this to be part of any sampler (i.e pre-processor; post-processor). I simply want to start my thread group (which will loop) and check if a couple cookies exist. If they don't, I will login. If they do, I will run the rest of my tests and loop again.

[image]

I've tried several different things. The two methods I see for pulling the cookie manager is:

```
CookieManager cm = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getCookieManager();
```

and

```
CookieManager cm = sampler.getCookieManager();
```

I keep getting the error:

> javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method
>   getCookieManager() on null object

I've created a JSR223 pre-processor, post-processor, and assertion and none of them seem to work.

I just want the cookies that are currently stored in the HTTP Cookie Manager which is global to the thread. There is no associated sampler. Why in the world are these methods related to a specific sampler when the cookie manager isn't even local to the sampler? I'm checking the cookies BEFORE I run any sampler.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you're violating [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/) or [Test Elements Execution Order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder), it is quite hard to tell what's wrong as your screenshot doesn't demonstrate full structure of the test plan. None of pre/post processors or assertions will work **without sampler** :

[image]

Actually you don't even need any scripting, if you [add the next line to *user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous):

```
CookieManager.save.cookies=true
```

then you will get cookies exposed in form of `${COOKIE_XXX}` where `XXX` is the cookie name, the variable can be used i.e. in the [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I don’t want this to be part of any sampler. The existence of specific cookies decides what samplers are run. The `save.cookies` parameter is ineffective as it sets the variables but does not unset them when the cookie is gone - rather useless. I simply want to get a cookies object and perform an if controller on the contents of a specific cookie. The cookies will exist because of previous sampler calls either from the previous loop or earlier in the thread.

Comment: For instance, I will login to a website then proceed to run several requests in a loop. If at any point I get logged out (lose my authentication cookie) I will need to login again before continuing my loop.